# SQL Select Based On Max Value of One Column and Specific Id from Another

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I am trying to return one value of a column based on the max value of another column and a specific id of a third column, all these in the same table.

I tried to do the following sql, but it does not work:

```
SELECT "value" 
FROM event_log 
   JOIN (SELECT MAX("time") AS max_time 
         FROM event_log WHERE "eid" = 6)
```

The only value I want is the "value" column based on the maximum value and a specific id number of other columns of the same table.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `ON` clause of the `JOIN` operation:

```
SELECT "value" 
FROM event_log AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT MAX("time") AS max_time 
   FROM event_log 
   WHERE "eid" = 6
) AS t2 ON t1."time" = t2.max_time
WHERE t1."eid" = 6
```

Comment: What if two rows have the same time?  probably need `WHERE "eid" = 6` in the outer query.

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns more rows with different "eid"s.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "value" 
FROM event_log AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT MAX("time") AS max_time, eid 
   FROM event_log 
   WHERE "eid" = 6
   Group By eid
) AS t2 ON t1."time" = t2.max_tim 
AND t1.eid = t2.eid
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using a subquery, and trying to join it to an existing table, but, unless you want a full join (and you would need to explicitly specify that by including the phrase `Full Join` in the query if that's what you want), you need to specify join conditions for the join, which you do not.
2. You need an alias for a subquery before you can use it in the rest of the outer query.
3. and finally, you are attempting to select a column named `value` from the subquery. But there is no column named `value` in that subquery. Is the column `value` in the `event_log` table?

But I don't think you need a join at all. Try this:

```
SELECT "value",
  (Select MAX("time")
   FROM event_log WHERE "eid" = 6) maxTime
FROM event_log l
```

Comment: Yes, the column "value" is in the event_log table.